# ndarray: How to split an array?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

Looking for the functionality of the `.split_of` function as used with a `Vec` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off)

Currently I am trying to use the function `split_at`: (docs: https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.split_at)

Usage:

```
let mut data: Array2<f32> = array![[1.,2.],[3.,4.],[5.,6.],[7.,8.]];
let split = data.split_at(Axis(0),1);
```

Getting the error:

```
method not found in `ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<{float}>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, these are defined only for [`ArrayView`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/type.ArrayView.html)s and not [`Array`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/type.Array.html)s.

It's unfortunate that this is stated right above [`split_at`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.split_at) in the documentation, making it easy to miss if you simply click on it from the sidebar of methods.

> Methods for read-only array views.

similarly for read-write views.

Initializing a view and splitting it as shown in `split_at`'s documentation should work fine.

Comment: My concern about this is its memory usage, working with very large arrays, doubling memory usage is really not viable. Do you know the memory usage of this approach?